How to draw Skia Svg Path with stroke and fill, but with different stroke color
I want to draw a path using skia in my maui project, but I want to use a different color for the stroke then for the fill, for example I want to draw some path with a black border and filled with red.
I tried this
SKPath sVgPath = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData(path); // path holds the svg path as a string
sVgPath.Transform(_matrix);

paint.Color = SKColors.Red;
paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill;

paint.Color = SKColors.Black;
paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;

canvas.DrawPath(sVgPath, paint);

but the rendered shape is not filled with red, it seems like the paint style stroke clears the red again.
I also tried to stroke first and then fill, but then the stroke is gone again.
Can this be done ? Seems simple to me but I can't figure it out
EDIT
I am using VS 2022
the project is maui using net8.0 and intended for android

Could you please include in the question what .NET version and platform do you use?

@LiqunShen-MSFT I edited the question, is this what you wanted ? if not please tell me what you need

Thanks for your feedback. Please also try my answer.

You may try setting strokePaint and fillPaint separately.
SKPaint strokePaint = new SKPaint
{
    Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
    Color = SKColors.Red,
    StrokeWidth = 20
};

SKPaint fillPaint = new SKPaint
{
    Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
    Color = SKColors.Blue
};

And draw the path according to whether the path is stroked or filled or both, and in what order:
        canvas.DrawPath(path, strokePaint);
        canvas.DrawPath(path, fillPaint);

For more info, you may refer to The Path Fill Types.

That worked, thank you
